# Get Contact Name Through Contact Number

Tags: android

i need to display contact name when user enter contact number .And click on Show Contact Name Button.
My Layout Xml File Content 3 Field
1.Edit Text(where user enter contact no.)
2.Text View(where contact name display when button pressed)
3.Button
Here my activity class for better understand

```
public class ContactNameActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button buttonshow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ShowName);
        final EditText textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edittext_Number);
        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_ContactName);
        buttonshow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    //here i need String ContactName

                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(ContactName));

                }

            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) { 
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));


    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }   


    return name;

}
```